# Why IP masquerade (source NAT) in linux kernel fails to set source IP on high packet rates

Tags: linux, nat, masquerade

I am trying to test throughput of the standard linux NAT. I have setup the following virtual network:

```
[192.168.42.5] <--> [192.168.42.2:192.168.35.2] <--> [192.168.35.10]
```

The middle host has 2 interfaces, runs ubuntu 14.04 and is configured as NAT:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eht1 -j ACCEPT
```

The `[192.168.42.5]` host also has the route rule for the second network:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.35.0/24 via 192.168.42.2 dev eth1
```

Then I run `hping3` on the `[192.168.42.5]` host:

```
sudo hping3 192.168.35.10  -k -s 3453 -S -n -p 80 -i u1000
```

And I also watch the communication on the `[192.168.35.10]` with `tcpdump`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth1
```

The system works OK on the rates ~1k Pkt/second. `tcpdump` displays arriving packets:

```
IP 192.168.42.5.3453 > 192.168.35.10.http: Flags [S], seq 1520954148, win 512, length 0
```

But when I increase the packet rate (with `-i u700` key), for some reason the NAT fails to rewrite the source address, and the target gets packets like this:

```
IP 192.168.42.5.3453 > 192.168.35.10.http: Flags [S], seq 1554999038, win 512, length 0
```

and ignores them having no available route to the `192.168.42.0/24` subnet, so `hping3` does not get any response. If that happened, I need to relax and wait for about 1-2 minutes, until I can get NAT to the normal operation even on the slow packet rates.

Why does NAT fail so weirdly? If it lacks capacity, why does it stil forward unmodified packets?

P.S. When I set-up the usual router instead of the NAT (with the corresponding rule in the `[192.168.35.10]` host), it routinely handles even 10k Pkt/s rates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be the `-k` flag.  From what I see, you set up a very unusual setup creating high volumes of connections with the same source/destination.  IPtables is a statefull firewall and tracks each connection individually.  I would speculate that you end up creating a high volume of collisions in a hash table.  This generally slows down access which may be what you are seeing.

The router may be operating in a stateless or semi-stateful manner.  This reduces the overhead involved.

Comment: Depending on the router model, NAT may be handled in hardware. Cisco claims that is required, which is why its layer-3 switches (except the 65xx series) can't do NAT.

Comment: How can it track each connection individually? What is the difference if they all have identical <src.ip, src.port, dst.ip, dst.port, protocol>?

Comment: You are right, though. Without `-k` it performs like the router.

Comment: @Necto The conntrack moudule keeps a table of active connections. When you have identical <src.ip, src.port, dst.ip, dst.port, protocol> the table has to deal with key collisions for tracking. Key collisions slow down look-up code.